# PHP Login script does not work

Tags: php, authentication, foreach

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now. I don't know why but the script wont work after I click the login button. I think that the mistake is probably in foreach.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) AND (!empty($_POST['username']) AND (!empty($_POST['password'])))) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $pass = hash('sha256',$password);

    $select = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :username AND password= :password");
    $select->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $select->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $select->execute();
    $result = $select->fetchAll();  

    foreach ($result as $data) {
        if ($data['username'] == $username AND $data['password'] == $password) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];?>
            <div class="echos">
                <?php
                echo "Login completed" . "<br>";
                echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/'>Homepage</a>";?>
            </div>
        <?php
        } else {
            echo "Wrong username or password!" . "<br>";
            echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/include/registration.php'>Try again</a>";
        }       
    }   
} else {
    echo "Fill all fields!" . "<br>";
    echo "<a href='http://jezecek.nostools.cz/include/login.php'>Try again</a>";
}?>
```

Comment: What's the error/issue? "the script wont work" is too generics

Comment: As an aside - you might want to look at `password_hash` rather than `hash` since you're not salting your password currently : http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Your current password hash is a variable called `$pass` yet you're binding `$password` into the query which is the plain text password - I assume you're actually storing the hash in the database so you should be binding `$pass`

Comment: The site isnt printing any error - after I fill the inputs and send the script, it just heads me to other page. But it should load the homepage when the values in inputs are right